# Partial names as tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have been adding a number of partial names as tag synonyms recently. For example:

- [yahari-ore-no-seishun](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahari-ore-no-seishun) (from "yahari-ore-no-seishun-rabu-kome-wa-machigatteiru") and [my-teen-rom-com-snafu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-teen-rom-com-snafu) (from "my-teen-romantic-comedy-snafu") as synonyms of [oregairu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oregairu)
- [blood-blockade](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-blockade) (from "blood-blockade-battlefront") as a synonym of [kekkai-sensen](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kekkai-sensen)
- [dungeon-ni-deai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-ni-deai) (from "dungeon-ni-deai-wo-motomeru-no-wa-machigatteiru-darou-ka) as a synonym of [danmachi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danmachi)
- [soredemo-sekai-utsukushii](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soredemo-sekai-utsukushii) (from "soredemo-sekai-wa-utsukushii"), [world-is-still-beautiful](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-is-still-beautiful) and [the-world-still-beautiful](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-world-still-beautiful) (from "the-world-is-still-beautiful") as synonyms of [soreseka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soreseka)
- [yuuki-yuuna-yuusha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuuki-yuuna-yuusha) (from "yuuki-yuuna-wa-yuusha-de-aru") as a synonym of [yuki-yuna-is-a-hero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuki-yuna-is-a-hero)
- and many others that you can see at https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

I don't *like* doing this (these partial-name synonyms are incredibly ugly and I would much prefer to have more characters available for tag names), but I think that this is one good way to help ensure that low-rep users trying to ask questions about these long-named series are able to find a tag for what they're looking for.

For example, it is entirely possible that a person who has watched Oregairu will not actually know that it is often abbreviated "Oregairu", and will instead try to type the title they know - either Japanese "Yahari Ore no..." or English "My Teen Romantic...". With these ugly partial-name synonyms in place, the odds they'll find what they're looking for is higher.

Does this seem like a good idea? Should I continue doing this?

Comment: A better idea is to ask SE to increase the tag character limit to VARCHAR.

Comment: @nhahtdh I wish: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209248/

Answer (score 4):

I support this idea, despite it being a monstrous, horrible hack.

I read your answer on the Stack Exchange meta post arguing for longer tag limits ([here it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259377) for anyone who hasn't seen it) and agree with everything you said. I don't see why it would be a problem to have tags go to … after 25 characters if having long tags creates some layout problem. I suspect the 25-character limit was just a decision the developers made early on for expediency, which has now become a problem.

On the other hand, I'm somewhat pessimistic that what I would expect to be a rather large change to the code will be made on behalf of a tiny site like Anime and Manga, or even a larger site like Movies and TV. I suspect this hack is what we're going to be stuck with. And it is better than having the "official" abbreviation be our only tag name, especially when the "official" abbreviation is as bizarre as these:

- Boku wa Tomodachi ga Sukunai is "Haganai"
- Watashi ga Motenai no wa Dou Kangaetemo Omaera ga Warui! is "Watamote"
- Yahari Ore no Seishun Rabu Kome wa Machigatteiru is "Oregairu"
- Saenai Heroine no Sodatekata is "Saekano"

It looks as if they just picked some random syllables during a linear sweep of the full title. At least if [tomodachi-ga-sukunai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomodachi-ga-sukunai) is a tag, I can type part of the title into the tag search bar and have something pop up.

I fear that we're stuck with this for now. I guess if Stack Exchange won't grant our request for longer tags, we could try lobbying the anime industry in Japan to pick shorter titles that would fit in 25 characters.

Comment: (FYI, in case you were wondering, the Haganai thing arises like this: if you write it in Japanese, you get 僕**は**友達**が**少**ない**; I've bolded the non-kanji [i.e. kana] glyphs in that title, which are は, が, な, and い. That is, "ha", "ga", "na", and "i". Thus, "Haganai". Why this ended up being the standard abbreviation I don't know, but there you have it.)

Comment: @senshin I did figure that out after staring at it for a minute or two the first time I saw it, but it's still a very bizarre abbreviation, especially for people who know even less Japanese than I do. Sadly, it's not the most bizarre in that list. I can only assume "Saekano" comes from some weird furigana trick where "heroine" is also read as "kanojo"

Comment: Yup, that's how "Saekano" happens. You write it "kanojo" and then stick furigana on it that say "heroine". Classic light novel buffoonery.

Comment: @senshin Seriously, we should just lobby the Japanese publishers to stop using such long, crazy names. The Japanese release of "Snakes on a Plane" changed the title to "Snakeflight"--why can't light novel publishers use the same standards?